# Where did my answer to a now-migrated question go?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I post an answer to [Adding components to JPanels dynamically during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368717/adding-components-to-jpanels-dynamically-during-runtime), but before or during migration this post was deleted or lost,

and this message isn't accesible for me

[image]

can moderator answer ma what's happened

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to read the entire comment by going directly to the [deleted post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/123093/8). Your post was deleted prior to migration as it didn't directly answer the question but was a critique on the supplied code. Stack Exchange isn't a discussion board: if you don't have an direct answer, please don't use the answer section to add commentary.

If you have a direct answer to the question now, feel free to post it on [the migrated question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368717/adding-components-to-jpanels-dynamically-during-runtime).

Comment: I can't see my deleted answer there, then why I aked my question, thanks for confirmation +1